# Why does setting an initialization value prevent placing a variable on a GPU in TensorFlow?

Tags: initialization, tensorflow, gpu

I get an exception when I try to run the following very simple TensorFlow code, although I virtually copied it from the documentation:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
  x = tf.Variable(0, name="x")

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(x.initializer) # Bombs!
```

The exception is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to
node 'x': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because
no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
```

If I change the variable's initial value to `tf.zeros([1])` instead, everything works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
  x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name="x")

sess = tf.Session()     
sess.run(x.initializer)  # Works fine
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error arises because `tf.Variable(0, ...)` defines a variable of element type `tf.int32`, and there is no kernel that implements `int32` variables on GPU in the standard TensorFlow distribution. When you use `tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))`, you're defining a variable of element type `tf.float32`, which *is* supported on GPU.

The story of `tf.int32` on GPUs in TensorFlow is a long one. While it's technically easy to support integer operations running on a GPU, our experience has been that most integer operations actually take place on the **metadata** of tensors, and this metadata lives on the CPU, so it's more efficient to operate on it there. As a short-term workaround, several kernel registrations for `int32` on GPUs were removed. However, if these would be useful for your models, it would be possible to [add them as custom ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html).

---

**Source:** In TensorFlow 0.10, the Variable-related kernels are [registered](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/854146110b5ec6b087fc6f2e18f35cc3b98e7186/tensorflow/core/kernels/variable_ops.cc#L55) using the [`TF_CALL_GPU_NUMBER_TYPES()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/854146110b5ec6b087fc6f2e18f35cc3b98e7186/tensorflow/core/framework/register_types.h#L162) macro. The current "GPU number types" are `tf.float16`, `tf.float32`, and `tf.float64`.

Comment: @mrry: Is there a difference in the way tensor variables are initialized when executing through Jupyter notebook and through python terminal?
I tried the above initilization code using tf.zeros on jupyter and by default a int32 tensor is initialized. However, the same code return a float32 tensor in x when run on python terminal.