# Tensorflow can not run integer matrix multiplication on GPU

Tags: tensorflow

Take a look at this example, where I attempt to multiple two `tf.int32` matrices using my GPU.

```
import tensorflow as tf
matrix1 = tf.constant([[3,3]])
matrix2 = tf.constant([[2],[2]])

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    product = tf.matmul(matrix1,matrix2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(product)
    print(result)
```

It is similar to the example found on https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/basic_usage.html

I get the output:

```
...
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7715
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 213.62MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:839] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] Cannot assign a device to node 'MatMul': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_INT32, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/device:GPU:0"](Const, Const_1)]]
```

Why can't I perform a matrix multiplication on the GPU? I can fix this by using `allow_soft_placement = True`, but I would like to do this on the GPU..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integer multiplication is currently not implemented for the GPU in TensorFlow, and your matrices `matrix1` and `matrix2` have type `tf.int32`. (It turns out that it is easy to implement but, for various reasons discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133562/3574081), TensorFlow doesn't include op registrations for `tf.int32` on GPU devices.)

Assuming you are actually interested in multiplying (much larger) floating-point matrices, you can change your program to:

```
import tensorflow as tf
matrix1 = tf.constant([[3., 3.]])
matrix2 = tf.constant([[2.], [2.]])

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    product = tf.matmul(matrix1,matrix2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(product)
    print(result)
```

...and the multiplication will execute on your GPU.

Comment: Oh, that's the reason, thank you! I see that using `dtype=tf.float16` is also possible to use on the GPU. Then the matrices will take less space, and I can do larger matrices, right?

Comment: That's correct - and on some GPUs the matrix multiplication should be twice as fast using `tf.float16` (not sure about the GTX 1080 though).